# Insert { in > array preamble and } in < array preamble

Tags: tables, columns

The `>` and `<` preamble options of the `array` package (and possibly other table packages) allow automatically inserting text and commands before and after each cell of a column, respectively.

Can they be used to insert things like `\hyperlink{foo}{` before and `}` after each cell, or something like that? Attempts so far:

- `>{  \hyperlink{foo}{  }  c  <{  }  }` causes an error because the braces are unbalanced.
- Escaping the braces by `\{` just inserts braces into the PDF.
- `>{  \begin{hyperlink}{foo}  }  c  <{  \end{hyperlink}  }` interestingly causes sharelatex to complain about the closed brace between `begin` and `end`, but does not cause a latex error.

  The problem though is that this results in `\begin{hyperlink}{foo}text in cell\end{hyperlink}`, adding a hyperlink only to the first letter "t", whereas I need the result to be `\begin{hyperlink}{foo}{text in cell}\end{hyperlink}`, and for some reason not even surrounding every cell entry by braces manually helps.

Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: `collcell` allows you to wrap a macro around cell contents.

Comment: Should all items in the column share the hyperlink `foo`?

Comment: @egreg Yes, but other columns and other tables should have other hyperlinks.

Comment: @root My answer covers this, doesn't it?

Comment: @egreg Yes, thanks, I'll try it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If all items in a column share the target, you just need to specify it: an additional pair of braces is all you need in the `\collectcell` part.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{collcell}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\newcolumntype{h}[1]{%
  >{\collectcell{\hyperlink{#1}}}c<{\endcollectcell}%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{h{foo} h{bar}}
to foo 1 & to bar 1 \\
to foo 2 & to bar 2
\end{tabular}

\newpage\hypertarget{foo}{This is foo}
\newpage\hypertarget{bar}{This is bar}

\end{document}
```

If you need to specify different targets, brace the items together with their target.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{collcell}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\newcommand{\makehyperlink}[1]{\makehyperlinkaux#1}
\newcommand{\makehyperlinkaux}[2]{\hyperlink{#1}{#2}}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{>{\collectcell\makehyperlink}c<{\endcollectcell}}
{foo}{a}\\
{bar}{b}\\
\end{tabular}

\newpage\hypertarget{foo}{FOO}

\newpage\hypertarget{bar}{BAR}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use `collcell`. If you want to use the column type `p`, you need to add a width, so for the time being I chose `c`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{collcell}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\newcommand{\Foo}[1]{\hyperlink{foo}{#1}}
\newcolumntype{H}{>{\collectcell\Foo}c<{\endcollectcell}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{H}
a\\
b\\
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Would also something like `>{\collectcell\hyperlink{foo}}...` work, without defining a new command for every possible *first* argument of `\hyperlink`?

Comment: @root Honestly, I do not know. According to what I know this might be the simplest option.

Comment: @root `\collectcell\hyperlink{foo}` clearly can't work, but I assume `\collectcell{\hyperlink{foo}}`  will

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thanks! Yes it does. `\newcolumntype{H}{>{\collectcell{\hyperlink{foo}}}c<{\endcollectcell}}`. There is a follow up question that is waiting for an answer, I believe.