# Table cell as one of several arguments of a command issued via >{} and <{}

Tags: tables, columns

Is an extension of [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/504705/88051) or [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/514224/88051) possible such that [an additional argument to the issued command is passed directly](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/514223/insert-in-array-preamble-and-in-array-preamble#comment1300362_514224) without defining a new command or macro for each possible argument?

Comment: a question with just links is hard to  follow or test answers, please supply a test document

Answer (score 2):

`\collectcell` takes an argument, which is applied to a brace group which contains the cell contents, there is no requirement that that first argument is a single token so you can do for example

```
\collectcell{\hyperlink{foo}}
```

which if the cell contents are `... & zzz & ...`

will execute

```
 \hyperlink{foo}{zzz}
```

and make the intended link.

Comment: This is the same as I suggested in my more thorough answer to https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/514223/insert-in-array-preamble-and-in-array-preamble

Comment: @egreg so it is (although that answer wasn't there when I  started to write this:-) Close this one as dup?

Comment: It's more complicated with `\newcolumntype`. Yes, it seems answered now under egreg's link.

Comment: @root no it's exactly the same, as egreg showed. `\newcolumntype`  definitions are expanded out before the tabular starts so anything that ypu can do directly in a tabular preamble you can do in necolumntype